# Supress warnings of 4xx response code of views in Django

Tags: django, logging

I am trying to suppress some specific warning message of a view that's returning a 404 when the object is not found. I have tried:

```
 try:
     city = Cities.objects.get(id='abcd')
 except ObjectDoesNotExist:
     with warnings.catch_warnings():
         return bad_request_response(_('City not found.'), resp_status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

But django seems to go around that and shows in the logs:

```
WARNING Not Found: /cities/abcd/
```

I am working with Django 1.11. I see it the docs that this is the expected behavior https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/#django-request but I am trying to go around that. Any hint is welcome

Comment: Could you please provide an extended sample code of the view that these lines are used in? Seeing your query for getting the object would be a first step.

Comment: Added some more context.

Comment: Is there something preventing the use of `filter` instead of `get` and then giving different responses depending on whether the resulting Queryset is empty or not?

Comment: I need the 404 to be raised so the response doesn't change at all. The intention is just to change the logging.